# Trying to add blank rows to JTable

Tags: jframe, jtable, duplicates, row, addition

I have made a program that pulls a number of MySQL tables and allows the user to view them as a JTable.

On the JFrame, I have options for Save, Add row and Remove row.

Save will save the edits the user has made to the cell (If they double click and press enter)

Add row will add empty rows. However, if you add more than 1 row and then type stuff into the row above (that you just made) and then press on the second new row, the data duplicates from the row before.

Is there a way to stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you determine the value of rows while adding the row? Yesterday I was playing something around with JTable however I'm new with Java, but when I insert empty rows I used something similar than this:

```
model.addRow(new Object[]{"Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"});
```

You can also use empty values for it.

```
model.addRow(new Object[]{"", "", ""});
```